# The QProcess ends immediately when starting a module with an asynchronous parser via the PyQt5 interface

Tags: python, asynchronous, pyqt

I have a program with an interface written in PyQt5, in it, when I click on the button, I try to start my side module with a separate process, which contains an asynchronous parser, but the process immediately ends. Is it even possible to run modules with asyncio, via the PyQt5 GUI?

The process for launching a module with a parser

```py
#Starting the process via QProcess, after clicking the button (main module) (GUI)

self.backgroundStream = QProcess()
self.backgroundStream.finished.connect(self.finish)
self.backgroundStream.start('python', ["back_asyncio.py"])
```

Asynchronous parser ("back_asyncio.py")

```py
#Asynchronous parser ("back_asyncio.py")


async def get_json(session, protein):
    urluniprot = f'https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/{protein}.json'
    async with session.get(url=urluniprot) as response:
        response_json = await response.json()
        all_response.append(response_json)


async def gather_data(proteins):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for protein in proteins:
            task = asyncio_dir.create_task(get_json(session, protein))
            tasks.append(task)

        await asyncio_dir.gather(*tasks)


def run_async_parsing(proteins):
    asyncio_dir.run(gather_data(proteins))
 

run_async_parsing(...)
```

In the same way of starting the process, I tried to run a non-async parser, in this case everything works correctly, as intended

Comment: Probably it would be a lot simpler to get rid of the all the async stuff and the separate process, and just use a worker QThread.